# How to know what parameters will be sent using a POST when reading a page source-code?

Tags: c#, post, https

I am creating an application that connects automatically to a website (not my creation) and handles login. I don't know how to figure out structure of the POST request. The connection is using HTTPS. Is it possible to know POST parameters and structure of POST header by looking page source code?

I am wondering how the browser figure those things out.
If there is a code, I am working with C#, but the idea is the main thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) when you using a browser to login on the website, to see what headers the browser sends to the website.

Comment: It seems what I am looking for, I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

A browser doesn't just conjure up a post request out of thin air - it's usually the result of an HTML form, which tells it the different elements, or an AJAX request written in Javascript. In each case, the server is effectively telling the browser what to send in the *next* request as part of the *current* response.

Assuming you're trying to mimic a browser, you should look at what would trigger the post request *from* a browser. If it's a form, look at the input elements of the form. If it's Javascript, look at what the code making the request is filling in.

Answer (score 1):

If you use plain HTML, the browser will send the value of every enabled input field within the <form> tag of the POSTing submit button: input, select, button, textarea.

See for example [this description](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/form.html).

If the page uses Javascript to post data (such as ASP.Net or AJAX), I guess it's generally impossible to figure out the posted data unless you use a Javascript interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The POST method is only the way parameters will transfer to the server. Look at [this sample](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/). At the first line you can see parameters wich would be transfered to server. To investigate parameters needed to your server you can try to use HttpFox plugin for fire fox

Comment: I know this thing, but the problem is in the prameters, hehe